# Color change loading GeoTIFF into QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, color

I have a JPEG RGB map image composed of 12 colours produced by a programme using a colour palette. It converts correctly to  a modified TIFF, which prints out correctly. But when this is loaded into QGIS it appears in the canvas and print-out with the two green shades rendered as white. How can I correct this?

Comment: The symbology of a TIFF in QGIS is randomly chosen as far as I am aware. Editing your symbology can be done by right-clicking your layer > properties > Symbology

Can you share more details about the type of symbology / data?

Comment: Symbology ismultiband color

Comment: Symbology
Color=multiband
red min 1 max 255 green min 64 max 255 blue min1 max255
contrast
enhancement none
min/max set6ting   min/max
color rendering
blending normal
brightness etc 0 greyscale off
resampling  in and out: nearest neighbour oversampling 2
QGIS version  is 3.10.4